# Using a condition to plot with matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, conditional-statements, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-D array and I need to plot columns x and y but only within a certain range of x. 
I know how to plot using the index but I need to specify the *value* of x. I have a few of those arrays so I am trying to find a way to do that without having to look at each one of them individually.

Here is an example:

```
array([[  4.40148390e+03,   1.13200000e+00],
       [  4.40248390e+03,   1.12200000e+00],
       [  4.40348440e+03,   1.11600000e+00],
       [  4.40448440e+03,   1.10600000e+00],
       [  4.40548490e+03,   1.09200000e+00],
       [  4.40648490e+03,   1.07700000e+00],
       [  4.40748540e+03,   1.08700000e+00],
       [  4.40848540e+03,   1.09400000e+00],
       [  4.40948580e+03,   1.10200000e+00],
       [  4.41048580e+03,   1.09500000e+00],
       [  4.41148630e+03,   1.12000000e+00]])
```

So let's say I only need `4402 < x < 4410` but I don't know the index. Can I put something like: `plot(x, y, where(4402 < x < 4410))`?

I feel like there is something obvious that I am missing here :p

Comment: `a[(a[:,0]>4402)&(a[:,0]<4410)]`

Comment: @mtadd Can you please post that as an answer (and maybe add some text explaining it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **matplotlib** to set limits on your x-axis so as not to display all the points in your data series.  However, we can filter your **numpy** array above as follows:

```
a = array([[ .... ]])
x = a[:,0]
y = a[:,1]

filter = (x>4402)&(x<4410)

plot(x[filter],y[filter])
```

Comment: If this answer is accepted, this question should be tagged **numpy**.